# SQLite openDatabase creating multiple databases

Tags: javascript, database, html, sqlite, opendatabase

I'm using this very common line of code to create a HTML 5 local SQLite database:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("testDB","1.0","A test SQLite database",20000);
```

If the database already exists openDatabase should open it, however with each refresh of my page a new database with identical details to the existing one(s) is created.  I am using Safari 5.1.2 to test this and viewing the storage via the error console -> Resources tab.

Comment: I've seen this as well in Safari, where the UI indicates multiple copies of the same DB and "creates" a new on on refresh. But if you exit Safari and come back to your site then there is only one. I chalked this up to a bug in Safari, as it doesnt happen in Chrome. That is, I dont think Safari is *really* creating multiple copies, just a UI bug.

Comment: I had considered the possibility of the problem being a Safari bug as well but never noticed that the 'phantom' db's vanish on re-opening Safari. Thanks for the tip, I will pretend they don't exist and hope we are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be a UI related bug introduced in Safari 5.1.2 and does not appear to have any impact on my webapps performance.

Will edit if I can find conformation of this being a UI bug.